# Dagger 2 acessing named dependencies in dependant module

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm converting a legacy codebase to a multi feature module architecture, and I'm currently trying to sort out my dagger setup, but having some issues.

I've got a top level AppComponent (AC) which has a dependant FeatureLegacyComponent (FLC). AC provides a couple of named Schedulers in a module, which I'm trying to expose to the FLC, but either I'm misunderstanding how this all hangs together or there's a bug in my setup somewhere.

I'm not entirely sure the best way of exposing named dependencies, but I've written something similar to this in the AC

```
@Component(
    modules = [
        AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class,
        SchedulerModule::class],
    dependencies = [BaseComponent::class,
        FeatureLegacyComponent::class]
)
@AppScope
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<MainApplication> {
    @Named("computation")
    fun computationScheduler(): Scheduler

    @Named("ui")
    fun uiScheduler(): Scheduler
}
```

With SchedulerModule looking like

```
@Module
class SchedulerModule {
    @Provides
    @Named("computation")
    fun providesComputationScheduler(): Scheduler = Schedulers.computation()

    @Provides
    @Named("ui")
    fun providesUiScheduler(): Scheduler = AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

    @Provides
    @Named("io")
    fun providesIoScheduler(): Scheduler = Schedulers.io()
}
```

But I'm still seeing errors indicating that the computation Scheduler isn't available in the FeatureLegacyComponent

```
OAuth2TokenRefreshInterceptor getOAuth2TokenRefreshInterceptor();
                                ^
      @javax.inject.Named("computation") io.reactivex.Scheduler is injected at
          com.meetup.feature.legacy.dagger.BusModule.providesBus(scheduler)
      com.meetup.feature.legacy.bus.RxBus is injected at
          com.meetup.feature.legacy.http.OAuth2TokenRefreshInterceptor.<init>(…, bus)
      com.meetup.feature.legacy.http.OAuth2TokenRefreshInterceptor is provided at
          com.meetup.feature.legacy.dagger.FeatureLegacyComponent.getOAuth2TokenRefreshInterceptor()
```

BusModule is an included module in the FLC

```
@FeatureLegacyScope
@Component(
    modules = {
        BusModule.class
    }
)
public interface FeatureLegacyComponent {...
```

and BusModule looks like this:

```
@Module(includes = {OtherModule.class})
public class BusModule {
  @Provides
  @FeatureLegacyScope
  RxBus providesBus(@Named("computation") Scheduler scheduler) {
    return new RxBus(scheduler);
  }...
```

What gives? What am I screwing up here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Component(
    modules = [..],
    dependencies = [..., FeatureLegacyComponent::class]
)
@AppScope
interface AppComponent
```

This makes your AppComponent dependant on FeatureLegacyComponent and not the other way around as you stated:

> I've got a top level AppComponent (AC) which has a dependant FeatureLegacyComponent (FLC)

That's why FeatureLegacyComponent can't access instances provided by your AppComponent. In order to fix it, you can either make FeatureLegacyComponent have dependency on AppComponent, or make FeatureLegacyComponent a [subcomponent](https://dagger.dev/subcomponents.html) of AppComponent.

Comment: I actually did it a slight different way: define an interface `FeatureLegacyComponentParent` which defines what dependencies `FeatureLegacyComponent` needs, then have `AppComponent` extend that interface & have `FeatureLegacyComponent` depend on the  `FeatureLegacyComponentParent` impl which is really the app component